# How to debug remote python code from local windows vs code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I want to debug python code (on remote linux) in local windows with VS code.

I did as follows:

1. In windows VS code, I can open remote linux python project using SSH.
2. Installed python debug tool ptvsd both in windows and remote linux.
3. Add code below in python project:

```
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach(address = ('$linux_ip', $port))
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```

4. Project `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "$linux_ip",
                "port": $port 
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "$my_real_linux_ws"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

5. Start run in remote linux.
6. Add break points in vs code, and run -> start debugging, then hit an issue as follows. I am confused that test.py is not in dir `/c4_working/test.py` but in dir `/c4_working/python_code/test.py`. And this file actually exists. So I am not sure why it would want to find the file in dir `/c4_working/test.py`? How would I fix it?

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue after creating a new launch.json file for this dir /c4_working/python_code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugging-by-attaching-over-a-network-connection) before asking your question?
A specially this part:
[image]

PS: strongly recommend to check [remote-pdb](https://pypi.org/project/remote-pdb/) as well.